# How set cursor to the top of page under UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How can i set the cursor focus on the top of the page when I clicked Update button.
Update button is under UpdatePanel

thank...

Comment: Your question isn't particularly clear.  Can you define what you mean by '_top of the page_' ?

Comment: You'll also need to post some code in your question - posting code helps people to understand your problem, which in turns helps you to get a solution.

Answer (score -1):

i'm not clear with what you mean (top of the page)
So, i assume you want to focus on text box.

To do this,
Add this in your page_load()'s

```
   if(!IsPostBack)
    {
       btnUpdate.Attributes.Add
         ("onclick","document.getElementById('<%= txtName.ClientID %>').focus()");
    }
```

Hope it works!
(not tested yet)

Comment: You want `"document.getElementById('" + txtName.ClientID + "').focus()"` server-side.

Comment: sorry for confusion.. i didnt to focus on the text box.. what im trying to say is to scroll up.. the screen should be on the top of the page..thanks